# How to detect if IndexedDB is enabled

Tags: javascript, browser-feature-detection

I'm wondering how to detect in JavaScript, whether or not IndexedDB is available and enabled.

I'm currently doing a test along these lines:

```
if (window.indexedDB) {
    if ((using_chrome && browserVersion >= 24)
        || (usingFirefox && browserVersion >= 16)
        || (usingIe && browserVersion >= 10)
        || (usingEdge && browserVersion >= 12)
        || (usingSafari && browserVersion >= 9)) {
        accessible = true;
    } 
}
```

But I would much prefer to use feature detection than relying on version numbers.

Assuming that feature detection for testing IndexedDB is efficient, does anyone know of a good way to test this on page load?

Comment: Maby have a look at https://modernizr.com ?

Comment: On the web, it is not recommended to whitelist browser features based on version numbers as you never know when a new browser might join the market. Rather, you should assume that a browser supports it, or attempt to detect it using a method such as the one Michał Perłakowski described, and otherwise only blacklist browsers you know that do not support said feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check it using [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/):

```
if (Modernizr.indexeddb) {
  console.log("IndexedDB is supported.");
} else {
  console.log("IndexedDB is not supprorted.");
}
```

Note that almost all modern browser support IndexedDB now (see [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=indexeddb)).

Comment: My concern is that the feature may be disabled by the user.  In that case, will these variables be falsey?

Does it seem reasonable to do a "test" of IndexedDB by saving/getting a value?

Comment: @user1431343 I think these variables would be `undefined`, which is falsy.

Comment: Safari/iOS 8 and 9 have extremely buggy indexedDB support (apparently fixed in Safari 10). You can reliably sniff the unreliable versions by using `var dontUseFaultyIndexedDB = /^Apple/.test(navigator.vendor) && /AppleWebKit[/]60.*Version[/][89][.]/.test(navigator.appVersion);`. See http://caniuse.com/#feat=indexeddb

Comment: Firefox in private mode doesn't support the IndexedDB but still returns something evaluating to True for window.indexedDB.

Answer (score 4):

Using some code from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB), you'll also want to fill in a couple other features as well:

```
// In the following line, you should include the prefixes of implementations you want to test.
window.indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;
// DON'T use "var indexedDB = ..." if you're not in a function.
// Moreover, you may need references to some window.IDB* objects:
window.IDBTransaction = window.IDBTransaction || window.webkitIDBTransaction || window.msIDBTransaction || {READ_WRITE: "readwrite"}; // This line should only be needed if it is needed to support the object's constants for older browsers
window.IDBKeyRange = window.IDBKeyRange || window.webkitIDBKeyRange || window.msIDBKeyRange;
// (Mozilla has never prefixed these objects, so we don't need window.mozIDB*)

if ( !window.indexedDB ) {
  alert("No DB");
}
```