# Firebase offline persistence for web app (Next JS, Node)

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I am creating a web app with Next JS (Node) that uses Firestore. The Firestore docs explain how to enable offline persistence for web, but whenever I try `enableIndexedDbPersistence(db)`, I get an error.

I have a file located at `src/firebase/initFirebase.ts`. Here is the code that creates the Firebase app and initializes the database:

```
import { FirebaseApp, initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import {
  enableIndexedDbPersistence,
  Firestore,
  getFirestore,
} from "firebase/firestore";

const clientCredentials = {
  apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGE_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
};

const firebaseApp: FirebaseApp = initializeApp(clientCredentials);

const db: Firestore = getFirestore(firebaseApp);
enableIndexedDbPersistence(db);

export { firebaseApp as default, db };
```

Here is the error that I get whenever I try to write to the database:

> FirebaseError: This platform is either missing IndexedDB or is known to have an incomplete implementation. Offline persistence has been disabled.

I have a couple of questions:

1. IndexedDB is built into the browser, right? So if I am using Chrome to run my web app, why would it not be supported?
2. What do I need to do to solve this issue?
3. If this is an issue with Node and there is no workaround, what is the best solution to still build an app that can cache data and read from that when it is offline?

Comment: can you check if IndexedDB is enabled refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34496096/how-to-detect-if-indexeddb-is-enabled)

Comment: @SathiAiswarya Yes, I checked using the reference you provided and IndexedB is supported on my browser (Chrome).

Comment: Add catch block after `enableIndexedDbPersistence` to see if the issue with browser or not ,check this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#configure_offline_persistence) also [Activate JavaScript in your browser](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/12654?hl=en#:~:text=Activate%20JavaScript%20in%20Google%20Chrome&text=Click%20Site%20settings.,Select%20Sites%20can%20use%20Javascript)